# Faster SQL DELETE WHERE IN/EXISTS needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table variable which i use to collect records from several tables, which have to be processed later on in my query.

It look a bit like this:

```
DECLARE @Prices TABLE ( 
  ProductId INT, 
  Price MONEY,
  Fee INT, 
  Discount INT,
  IsSpecialPrice BIT
)
```

Now, after gathering price related records from several tables (about 400K records), i have to delete just a few records. For the products for which i have at least 2 records (one or more with IsSpecialPrice = 0 and one with IsSpecialPrice = 1), i have to delete all records where IsSpecialPrice = 0.

Now using a DELETE WHERE IN or DELETE WHERE EXISTS takes way too long to get rid of there few records. So, i looking for a faster type of query here.

Right now this is what i use:

```
DELETE P1
FROM @Prices P1
WHERE P1.IsSpecialPrice = 0 AND EXISTS (SELECT P2.ProductId FROM @Prices P2 WHERE P2.ProductId = P1.ProductId AND P2.IsSpecialPrice = 1)
```

I tried both WHERE IN and WHERE EXISTS, but both are just as slow.

Comment: And what indexes exist/have you tried to create in order to speed things up?

Comment: With exists it is almost always faster to only select top 1. because you don't really care about the results just that there is at least one.

Comment: The query optimizers makes that the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about a join?

```
DELETE P1
FROM @Prices P1 join (
  SELECT DISTINCT ProductId
  FROM @Prices 
  WHERE IsSpecialPrice = 1
) P2 on P1.ProductId = P2.ProductId
WHERE P1.IsSpecialPrice = 0
```

i made a test on a table with 500k rows and completed in 2sec deleting 90k rows that's a huge improvement compared to the neverending `exists`.

Comment: This is the type of join that works super fast! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
DELETE P1
    FROM @Prices P1
    WHERE P1.IsSpecialPrice = 0 AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM @Prices P2
                  WHERE P2.ProductId = P1.ProductId AND P2.IsSpecialPrice = 1
                 );
```

The normal way to speed this up would be to add indexes:  `@Prices(IsSpecialPrice)` and `@Prices(ProductId, IsSpecialPrice)`.  Alas, you cannot add indexes on table variables unless you are using SQL Server 2014 (new feature).

An alternative would be to store this in an explicit temporary table and add the indexes on that table.  So, use `#Prices` rather than `@Prices` for the table.

Comment: How about a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(IsSpecialPrice, ProductId)`? IIRC, unique constraints are implemented by indices, even unique constraints on table variables, so can be exploited in SQL Server versions where the ability to explicitly create an index is not supported. (I'm assuming that `ProductId` is unique.)

Answer (score 0):

I find joins are almost always faster so I would write the query as such

```
DELETE P1
FROM @Prices P1
INNER JOIN @Prices P2 ON P2.ProductId = P1.ProductId AND P2.IsSpecialPrice = 1
WHERE P1.IsSpecialPrice = 0
```

If this still isn't giving the performance you want, you need to make them temp tables and index them appropriately as table variables don't allow indexing.

Comment: Using join was the right option, although this one didn't work. It was just as slow as my other options. But the one Paolo suggested was exactly what i needed!